# How to apply mutiple images to the material of UV Unwraped mesh

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

So, I've successfully modeled a sword in blender. Learned a lot. But still learning.

I followed some tutorials on youtube in order to learn how to texture the model.

However, what I've done is I've marked seams on several different parts of the Sword (Pommel, Hilt, Crossbar, Blade) And I've unwrapped each part separately. After this, I used a different image for each part of the blade.

I love the way it looks now, and I'd like to render it, but every time I try it doesn't show the textures I did with the UV Unwrap.

Upon further research, I found out that I have to make a material, and then apply the texture to the material.

My problem is that in every tutorial I've seen of this, its done differently, and most often the people in the tutorials are NOT working with multiple images.

Usually, they create a PNG. using their unwrapped objects, and the whole object is different colors but they're using a single Image, and I am not.

I'm very confused. I'd appreciate any help?

If possible, I'd like to simply take the way I have it textured with the UV unwrap (Which I can see when I change the viewport shading from "solid" to textured) and turn that directly into a texture that I can apply to a material, that I can assign to my model, and then render, without having to make multiple textures and multiple PNG.s and etc.

I need very clear, precise instructions, because I am very lost.

Any help would be appreciated.

**I'm using Blender Render, Not Cycles

Comment: Are you using Blender Render or Cycles?

Comment: Blender Render. @MutantBob

Comment: Don't feel lost! :) To better understand what you are asking: you would like to have a unique texture which is the ordinate merge of all the other like this one http://bit.ly/1Jek1Gt, or the problem rely on creating and rendering materials?

Comment: YES, I'm pretty sure that you've got the idea. Maybe I did it wrong, I followed a tutorial that useD the UV Editing to apply texture to a mesh. I did this, and marked the seams across each part that I wanted to give a different texture too, and then I used the Unwrap UV Image Editor to apply the textures I wanted, where I wanted them. Then I went to render it, and nothing happened. I realized I needed to select a material, and apply a texture to it. My problem was that I couldn't find a way to take my UV Unwrapped mesh, with the textures I applied, and use it on the material. @CarloBergonzini

Comment: Ok, that's  a sort of "packing" texture. These kind of texture are mostly associated to exporting a model with materials (es for game engines). If you just want to obtain a render, you probably don't need to do this.

Comment: Well great, but I still want the UV Unwrapped Mesh, with all the textures that I applied to it to show up in my render. And I don't know how to make them do that. @CarloBergonzini

Comment: Uhmm.. what do you exacly mean by talking about showing "UV Unwrapped Mesh"? Can you provide an example of what you want to come up with? Anyway I'm writing the full answer (it takes a bit.. )

Comment: I mean, I'd like all the textures I applied to the UV Unwrapped Mesh's of the model I made to appear when I render the image. In other words, I'd like to see the textures appear when I render the image. But I don't know how to do that accurately. Thank you for your help! Right now, the only way I can see the textures is when I put the viewport shading in Texture Mode. It doesn't appear otherwise, and doesn't show up in materials/textures, and definitely doesn't show up when I try render the image. @CarloBergonzini

Comment: Ok...while I'm finishing, check to have at least one light source in your scene, otherwise, despite they are textured and with a material, the always will come up black on rendering

Comment: Yeah, I definitely have a lightsource. The render always comes up grey/blank with only the model, and no texture or color. @CarloBergonzini

Comment: I would consider combining the images to make one image texture for the entire model. This is probably the most common and simplest approach for most situations. Unless you have a specific reason for using more than one image texture (like if they overlap; or if you already have one image that is laid out according to an existing UV map and you want to add some kind of detail using another image, or something like this), it is just easier to combine the images and go from there.

Comment: There are some related aswers around ([here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map), and [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19613/baking-to-multiple-objects-at-once-with-multiple-materials/20961#20961)). The question also is composed by 2 subquestion and the title probably must be rewritten.

Answer (score 3):

What I'm going to show you one possible way to to join different textured objects into a single object with a single texture.

Here's the roadmap:

[image]

Assuming that we are starting with two separate object with assigned textures as in the picture (Texture A for the cube, Texure B for the sphere):

[image]

First step is to create a material based on the assigned texture to each object.

**Part One - Creating basic textured materials in Blender Internal**

- Select one object (Cube in this case)
- Go to the Material tab
- Create new material (rename if wanted)
- Go to the Texture tab
- Create a new Material texture
- "Type" must be "image or movie"
- Choose the right texture from the built in browser (it will show you all the textures related to your file, so images you based your UV to must shown in the list)

[image]

A basic material where the texture is by default applied to the diffuse color of the shader has been created. Repeat the same processing for the other object.

The process is better explained in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nCJfC2pXZ4), or in this related [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23437/add-a-image-to-an-object)

**Part Two - Join texture in a texture atlas**

First step is about obtain a single object

- Merge all objects by selecting all of them and pressing ctrl+j

Now there is only one object with several materials applied. Blender conserves the information about what material was assigned to each face during the join operation.

By going in the "Object data" tab, you can see that there is only a UV map. This is because both of my objects had an UV map called "UVMap", so in the merging process the have been joined under the same name. Tey are now overlayed...but they still act as before in their proper texture space, as you can see in the viewport. If we want a single texture, we must avoid overlaying, so:

- Create a new UVMap by clicking the "+" button.

This new UV, called UVMap.001, will contain the uv info about the texture atlas we are going to create. Select this map, but don't set as "Active for rendering".

You can see here what UVMap you are working on:

[image]

In the UV/Image editor, clic on the "X" to clear the editor and than create a new image. This will be the image to bake to.
You can rearrange the UVs as you wish or let blender do the job by clicking "Pack island":

[image]

Go to the "Render" tab, in the Bake panel, bake mode, select "textures" in order to bake the textures of your object's materials (Texture A and Texture B) to the Image (Untitled.001) which is below your selected UV map (UVMap.001).

[image]

Comment: Maybe it looks more like a bad tutorial than an answer. Read it fast while I check the site guidelines...I might delete it! :(

Comment: You can also install and use the ["Texture atlas add-on"](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?265750-TextureAtlas-create-LightMaps-ShadowMaps-for-entire-scene) insted of doing manually as shown

Comment: Nice answer :) [Tutorial *requests* are off-topic](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/62/599), but both this question and answer are fine. In general a tutorial request is a question that asks for instructions on how to complete an entire project, such as "how to make a car". Questions about a specific issue (like "how to texture with multiple images") are more than welcome.

Comment: OK! Thanks for the clarification @gandalf3